# ExtJS: All stores loading at once

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

My application.js file is defined as shown below.  As you can see, there are a lot of stores and views to load.

The problem is, they are loaded asynchronously.  So, if a user clicks a button before the store has been loaded, it will not work.

If I wait until all stores have been loaded, it will work as intended.

How can I only load a store when it is required; or, what is a better solution to this problem?

```
Ext.define('RateManagement.Application', {
    name: 'RateManagement',

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    views: [
        // TODO: add views here
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.CountryRateGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.LocationRateGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.ComboBox.CountryCombo',
        'RateManagement.view.ComboBox.CurrencyCombo',
        'RateManagement.view.ComboBox.LocationCombo',
        'RateManagement.view.ComboBox.RateTypeCombo',
        'RateManagement.view.Columns.CurrencyColumn',
        'RateManagement.view.Columns.RateTypeColumn',
        'RateManagement.view.Columns.LocationColumn',
        'RateManagement.view.Columns.RateTypeColumn',
        'RateManagement.view.Columns.CountryColumn',
        'RateManagement.view.ServiceSelect.ServiceSelect',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.AirShipmentGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.LocationWithYearOtherRateGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.CountryWithYearOtherRateGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.RealtorFeeRateGrid',
        'RateManagement.view.Grids.AirfareRateGrid'
    ],

    controllers: [
        // TODO: add controllers here
    ],

    stores: [
        // TODO: add stores here
        'RateManagement.store.CountryStore',
        'RateManagement.store.CurrencyStore',
        'RateManagement.store.LocationStore',
        'RateManagement.store.RateTypeStore',
        'RateManagement.store.LegalRateStore',
        'RateManagement.store.DeparturePackageRateStore',
        'RateManagement.store.HouseSearchStore',
        'RateManagement.store.LanguageTrainingStore',
        'RateManagement.store.TempLiving1BedroomStore',
        'RateManagement.store.TempLiving2BedroomStore',
        'RateManagement.store.TempLiving3BedroomStore',
        'RateManagement.store.TransportationLuxury',
        'RateManagement.store.TransportationMidSize',
        'RateManagement.store.LanguageTrainingStore',
        'RateManagement.store.AirShipmentStore',
        'RateManagement.store.ServiceStore',
        'RateManagement.store.HomeSearchTripLodgingStore',
        'RateManagement.store.HomeSearchTripCarRentalStore',
        'RateManagement.store.HomeSearchTripMealsStore',
        'RateManagement.store.SchoolSearchStore',
        'RateManagement.store.RealtorFeeStore',
        'RateManagement.store.AirfareStore'
    ],

    models: [
        'RateManagement.model.Country',
        'RateManagement.model.Currency',
        'RateManagement.model.Location',
        'RateManagement.model.CountryRate',
        'RateManagement.model.LocationRate',
        'RateManagement.model.CountryRate',
        'RateManagement.model.Service',
        'RateManagement.model.AirShipmentModel',
        'RateManagement.model.RealtorFeeModel',
        'RateManagement.model.AirfareRate'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        //app launch code

        //stupid fix for stupid bug
        Ext.override(Ext.grid.RowEditor,{

          addFieldsForColumn: function(column, initial) {
            var me = this,
                i,
                length, field;


            if (Ext.isArray(column)) {
                for (i = 0, length = column.length; i < length; i++) {
                    me.addFieldsForColumn(column[i], initial);
                }
                return;
            }


            if (column.getEditor) {


              field = column.getEditor(null, {
                  xtype: 'displayfield',
                  getModelData: function() {
                      return null;
                  }
              });
              if (column.align === 'right') {
                  field.fieldStyle = 'text-align:right';
              }


              if (column.xtype === 'actioncolumn') {
                  field.fieldCls += ' ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-action-col-field';
              }


              if (me.isVisible() && me.context) {
                  if (field.is('displayfield')) {
                      me.renderColumnData(field, me.context.record, column);
                  } else {
                      field.suspendEvents();
                      field.setValue(me.context.record.get(column.dataIndex));
                      field.resumeEvents();
                  }
              }
              if (column.hidden) {
                  me.onColumnHide(column);
              } else if (column.rendered && !initial) {
                  me.onColumnShow(column);
              }

              // -- start edit
              me.mon(field, 'change', me.onFieldChange, me);
              // -- end edit
            }
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Two options off the top.  To get sync load, you can turn off `autoload` and call the next store (and each subsequent store) from the callback of the `load` event (beware: this could easily lead to callback hell).  Another option is to fire a function on store load that counts the number of stores in total that are loaded. And once that number is equal to total stores allow interaction?

Comment: Is there a way to load the store whenever the Grid is first shown?  It seems to make sense that I should be able to load the data of the grid, only when the grid is requested.

Comment: You can set `autoLoad` to true on the store. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Autoload true seems to make everything load as soon as the app starts.  I would only want it to load when I click my link that shows the grid.  Is that possible?

Comment: sure you just need to add a `listener` to the `click` event and call store `load` (and set `autoload` to false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using controllers: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

With controllers you can split your application bootstrap class in multiple small controllers which were invoked and loaded when needed. They can have depenencies to models, stores and views which will be loaded when a new instance of the controller is created (e.g. when a user requests opening a new window).